# Client side fluent validation for unique email

Tags: .net, asp.net-mvc-4, asp.net-mvc-5, fluent, fluentvalidation

I am working with fluent API Version=8.0.0.0 and trying hard to achieve client side validation for unique email. Client side Validation is working fine but it is only working for firstname, lastname and for invalid email but it is not working for unique email where I need to check it from database. I am already using unobtrusive and jquery.

However Modelstate returns false if email is not unique. What sort of things can i do to fire the unique email validation client side?

```cs
public class OfferValidator : AbstractValidator<model>
{
  private  ApiService _apiService;
  public   OfferValidator(ApiService apiService)
  {
    _apiService = apiService;

    RuleFor(x => x.FirstName).NotEmpty()
                             .WithMessage("FirstName is required!");
    RuleFor(x => x.LastName).NotEmpty()
                            .WithMessage("LastName is required!");
    RuleFor(s => s.Email).NotEmpty()
                         .WithMessage("Email is required!")
                         .EmailAddress()
                         .WithMessage("Invalid email");
    RuleFor(x => x.Email).Must(IsEmailUnique)
                         .WithMessage("email-Id already exists!");
  }

  public bool IsEmailUnique(string email)
  {
    return this.apiService.GetCustomerByEmail(email) ? false : true;
  }
}
```

I have also gone through [this](https://www.jerriepelser.com/blog/remote-client-side-validation-with-fluentvalidation/) but I can't find " FluentValidationPropertyValidator" in this version of fluent API.

Answer (score 0):

Your comparsion seems odd. Try checking for null:

```
public bool IsEmailUnique(string email)
{
    return this._apiService.GetCustomerByEmail(email) != null;
}
```

Also, if you ask me, this should not be a validation task (is the data format following the rules?) but more a rule of business logic (only keep processing this email address, if it's unique).

Comment: No. My comparison is perfect. I am getting what I want but client side validation is not working on this. However my model state is false if email is duplicate

Comment: It's a smell if you use the conditional operator to return true and false.

Answer (score 0):

Fluent Validation is a server-side validation library. It supports some basic validations on client-side. (like required, maxlength etc.) You can't use all server-side rules on client-side. In default usage you need to post all page for server-side validations.

If you want to use Fluent Validation on client-side with fully support you need to write extra codes for that. There is a library on Nuget for your problem. Form Helper adds fully client-support to Fluent Validation.

[Form Helper](https://github.com/sinanbozkus/FormHelper)

You need to create your forms like this:

```
// <form asp-formhelper="true" asp-controller="Home" asp-action="Save" method="post>
// ...
```

After that you need to add **[FormValidator]** attribute to your action.

Now you can use all server-side rules on client-side.

Comment: This is a great tutorial from the man himself (you'll need to translate from Turkish)

http://www.sinanbozkus.com/form-helper-ve-fluent-validation-kullanarak-asp-net-core-validation-islemleri/